# Warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE

Tags: php

I have a text file named `1month.ssh`:

```
Host: m-sg5.portssh.com
Username: portssh.com-myuser
Password: mypass
Port: 443
Info: Your Account will expire on 02-January-2017
```

I'm trying to create an array based on that file with:

```
$infossh = parse_ini_string(preg_replace('/^([^:]+): (.+)$/m','$1 = $2',file_get_contents('/home/ab/gconf/'.$_POST['account'])));
```

`$_POST['account']` refers to `1month.ssh`. My goal is when I echo the array, each value should be like this:

```
$infossh['Host'] = "m-sg5.portssh.com"
$infossh['Username'] = "portssh.com-myuser"
$infossh['Password'] = "mypass"
$infossh['Port'] = "443"
$infossh['Info'] = "Your Account will expire on 02-January-2017"
```

But instead with that code I get the following error:

```
Warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in Unknown on line 5 in /www/ssh.php on line 218
```

How can I solve this ?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I have another file `sgdo.ssh`:

```
Host: x-sgdo19.serverip.co
Username: fastssh.com-myuser
Password: mypass
Port: 443
Info: Date Expired : 10-December-2016
```

But I get no error with this file, the error only occurs when I open `1month.ssh`

Comment: You have more than one `Host` in the same file?

Comment: @Perumal93 no only one sgdo.ssh and 1month.ssh are two different files

Comment: I mean those five lines recur for each host in the same file? You got my point?

Comment: I don't really get your point but I have some files with the same format, I think there's something wrong with the regex in my code but I'm not sure @Perumal93

Comment: Are those files generated automatically?

Comment: @Perumal93 no it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Host: m-sg5.portssh.com
Username: portssh.com-myuser
Password: mypass
Port: 443
Info: Your Account will expire on 02-January-2017
```

Here, the `Info`'s value should be wrapped in quotes.

**EDIT**

```
$infossh = file('1month.ssh', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$new_infossh = [];

array_walk($infossh, function($element, $index) {
    global $new_infossh;
    $element_temp = explode(': ', $element);
    $new_infossh[$element_temp[0]] = $element_temp[1];
});

var_dump($new_infossh);
```

I've modified my code above to more simplified one.

```
$infossh = file('1month.ssh', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$new_infossh = [];

foreach($infossh as $value) {
    $value_arr = explode(': ', $value);
    $new_infossh[$value_arr[0]] = $value_arr[1];
}

var_dump($new_infossh);
```

In my point of view, these are two of the other ways you can make it without using regex. Hope it works!

Comment: That fixed it but is there a better way than this ?

Comment: Yeah. But without regular expression. Would you like to go for it?

Comment: Yeah. I can write without regex.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can have it without regex.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I've provided you the second one and I'm glad it's works for you. :)